# how to i send HTTP request for sending notification in firebase?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

> To send a notification, you'll need to send the following HTTP request:
>
> ```
> POST /fcm/send HTTP/1.1
> Host: fcm.googleapis.com
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY
>
> {
>   "notification": {
>     "title": "New chat message!",
>     "body": "There is a new message in FriendlyChat",
>     "icon": "/images/profile_placeholder.png",
>     "click_action": "http://localhost:5000"
>   },
>   "to":"YOUR_DEVICE_TOKEN"
> }
> ```

how can I do this??

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Node.JS, I suggest you look at the documentation for Firebase's Node.JS SDK instead of manually sending HTTP requests. There's [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send_to_individual_devices) or [this nice tutorial](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Sending_Firebase_Cloud_Messages_from_a_Node.js_Server#Installing_the_Firebase_Admin_SDK)

If you still want to go for the plain HTTP method, you can use the `request` npm module

```
$ npm install request
```

then in your code :

```
const request = require('request');

request({
  url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": ['key', yourServerKey].join('=')
  },
  json: {
    to: clientFirebaseToken,
    notification: {
      title: "Notification Title",
      body: "This is a neat little notification, right ?"
    }
  });
```

### Edit

From [their GitHub](https://github.com/request/request#readme)

> As of Feb 11th 2020, request is fully deprecated. No new changes are
> expected to land. In fact, none have landed for some time.

If you use `axios`

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": ['key', yourServerKey].join('=')
  },
  params: {
    to: clientFirebaseToken,
    notification: {
      title: "Notification Title",
      body: "Neat indeed !"
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: I have big troubles sending silent push notifications to IOS devices using the Node.JS Firebase SDK - Only 1 in 10ish devices actually receive them - I'm now opting for direct HTTP instead as mentioned above (fingers crossed)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React JS/ React Native, using the Axios package it can be done very easily, the sample code is below, first, you have to register for firebase cloud messaging to get the authorization key

```
axios.post(
          'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
          {
            data: {},
            notification: {
              title: "Sample text1",
              body: "Sample text2",
              image: "Sample text3",
            },
            to: '/topics/TopicName',
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization:
                'key=Authorization key from firebase',
              
            },
          },
        )
        .then(Response => {
          console.log(Response.data);
        });
```